# Javascript - how to wait for facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-fql

My app does the following:
1. Asks for the friends_online_presence permission.
2. If the user gave the permission (i.e the callback indicated success) I immidiately test for the permissions(*) and depending on the result pull the users' details (a call to getOnlineFriends).

The problem is that it takes a couple of miliseconds for facebook to update the permissions on their servers. So when I immidiately query for the permissions I just asked for facebook always says that I don't have the permission.
Using setTimout "solves" the problem.
How can this be solved deteministically?
I've tried some primitive form of polling but it got the browser stuck (and it also seems like a crooked solution).

(*) 'SELECT friends_online_presence FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()'

The code:

```
c2p.facebook = {
    requestViewOnlineFriendsPerms: function (callback) {
        myStuff.requestPermission('friends_online_presence', callback);
    },

    requestPermission: function (perms, callback) {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'permissions.request',
            perms: perms,
            display: 'popup'
        }, function (response) {
            if (response && response.perms) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(true);
                }
            } else if (!response.perms) {
                if (callback) {
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
        });

    fql: function (q, callback) {
        FB.api({ "method": "fql.query", "query": q }, callback);
    },

    getOnlineFriends: function (callback) {
        var q = 'SELECT friends_online_presence FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()';
        c2p.facebook.fql(q, function (rows) {
            var isPermissionGranted = true;
            var q2 = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square, online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active', 'idle') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name";

            if (rows[0].friends_online_presence == 0) {
                isPermissionGranted = false;
                q2 = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY name";
            }

            c2p.facebook.fql(q2, function (arr) {
                callback(arr, isPermissionGranted);
            });
        });
    }
}

// The way I call this code is:
c2p.facebook.getOnlineFriends(function (arr, isPermissionGranted) {
    $("#tmplFriends").tmpl(arr, { getIndex: function () { return $.inArray(this.data, arr); } }).appendTo("#friendsDiv");
    if (!isPermissionGranted) {
        $('.c2p_hidden').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: If it takes some time for fb to update their servers (and the success callback returns before then) then I don't think you *can* solve it deterministically. You would have to poll fb yourself until it's 'working', which is essentially what you're doing with the setTimeout. Unless you are not using the fb callback correctly.

Comment: can u show us what `callback` looks like? It might help.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I've added the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

How c2p.facebook.fql(q2, function (arr) {...} could see the *callback* variable? it's crazy.
The *callback* is a local variable of the getOnlineFriends function.

Comment: It's not crazy, it's closures. :)
I've simplified the code to an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/nk573/

Answer (score 0):

Tom just place your FQL query inside the

```
if (response && response.perms) {

}
```

for example suppose I want to fetch user details thru fql what I do is:

```
function onloginCall(){
      FB.login(handleSessionResponse,{perms:'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
  }
function handleSessionResponse(response){        
      // if we dont have a session, just hide the user info
      if (!response.session) {
          return;
      }
      else{
          FB.api({
                method: 'fql.query',
                query: 'SELECT name, pic_square , email FROM user WHERE uid=' + FB.getSession().uid
                 },

                 function(response) {
                      var user = response[0];
                      store_fbuser_data(FB.getSession().uid,user.name,user.pic_square,user.email) ;
                 }
          );
     }
}
```

I guess this will solve your problem of delay. As this query will only execute when you have sufficient permissions.